# What should the HTTP response code be for an endpoint whose role is to load a server cache?

Tags: api, rest, caching, http-response-codes

I need to create an endpoint that loads a server cache when called (for instance "POST cache/load") but I don't want that endpoint to load the cache if it's already loaded. Therefore, I want to differentiate, in my responses, the two following cases :

- "I loaded the cache, everything went fine"
- "The cache is already loaded, everything is fine"

Now the question is, what are the appropriate HTTP response codes ?

I currently use 201 when the cache has been loaded and 200 if the cache is already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the question is, what are the appropriate HTTP response codes ?

[200](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.3.1) for both.  That's all that the components in the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s) domain need to know.

The implementation specific details belong in the body of the response.